# installing stuff with node or bower

Tags: node.js, bower

I'm new to nodejs or thing like grunt. These are great tool but says I use npm install bootstrap, I will get node_module folder and still in that folder I have to get into dist folder to get what I want to start development. How can I set up my environment more faster?